# Would a muggle who married a wizard be allowed to move to Hogsmeade?

Tags: harry-potter

Hogsmeade is well known as the only entirely non-muggle settlement in the UK. But say that a wizard or witch marries a nice muggle and they decide together that they want to move to Hogsmeade. This would of course result in Hogsmeade no longer being a non-muggle settlement. Would they be allowed to do so?

Comment: I can just imagine the people in Hogsmeade getting all uppity about the muggles moving in next door, complaining about how it'll [ruin the neighbourhood and lower house prices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockbusting).

Comment: Since Hogmeade advertises itself as the only muggle-free community in the UK and since muggles have been freely interbreeding with wizards and witches for millennia, I should imagine that they have very strict zoning laws that prevent muggles from living there. That would be the only way that the town hasn't become mixed.

Comment: @Valorum - You see, based on the Grangers being allowed into Diagon Alley and the fact that a fair few characters have relationships with Muggles (at least as described on Pottermore) without too many issues, and the fact that Muggle-borns are not taken from their parents, I'd have said yes. But your point is good - as soon as one Muggle moves in, another will, and it gets diluted down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just going to out and out say "**no, they're not allowed to live there**". Not because I have any proof that Muggles *aren't* allowed but simply because their total absence suggests a guiding hand in keeping them out.

Pottermore describes [Hogsmeade](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/hogsmeade) as

> *The only **entirely non-Muggle** settlement in Britain*

However, we know from the books that [numerous](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Minerva_McGonagall) [witches](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sybill_Trelawney) and [wizards](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Severus_Snape) come from [mixed](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Seamus_Finnigan) Muggle/Magicfolk marriages.

So what keeps this vast number of mixed marriage Muggle partners from moving to a highly desirable location just a few minutes from the country's premiere school of Witchcraft and Wizardry? Answer, [racial zoning laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusionary_zoning).

---

You may wish to note that this isn't the first time segregation has been tried in the wizarding world. Hogsmeade may simply be following in the fine tradition of the [US wizarding community](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/rappaports-law-en)

> *Dorcus’s indiscretions led to the introduction of Rappaport’s Law.
>   Rappaport’s Law enforced strict segregation between the No-Maj and
>   wizarding communities. Wizards were no longer allowed to befriend or
>   marry No-Majs. Penalties for fraternising with No-Majs were harsh.
>   Communication with No-Majs was limited to that necessary to perform
>   daily activities.*

Comment: While the stated fact that no muggles live in Hogsmeade does require an explanation, the one that you propose doesn't seem to jibe with Rowling's philosophy. Do you have any source to support the idea of this approach in the UK wizarding world?

Comment: No-Maj means the same as Muggle?

Comment: @Thunderforge "No-Maj" is the American word for "Muggle" that's been introduced for the _Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them_ movie.

Comment: @Blackwood - The only evidence I could find is that the village is utterly Muggle-free and that this lack is one of the town's most notable (and presumably desirable) features.

Comment: It occurred to me that some muggle parents interested in magic (or helicopter parents) might also be interested in moving to Hogsmeade to be closer to their magical child, not just mixed parents.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I know a number of parents who bought property near to my university to use as crash-pad for when they came up.

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

A simple anti-Muggle spell—as elementary as making any Muggle approaching the village believe that they are going the wrong way, so that they turn around—would more than account for the lack of Muggles.  And it may be that combined with the magical community's desire to remain Muggle-free, the few Muggles who have married magical folk find magical society to lack many of the conveniences they like, so they live in a mixed community instead.

Muggles do from time to time visit the school (Myrtle's parents did, at least in the film adaptation of *Chamber of Secrets*), and they almost certainly pass through the village on their way in and out.  It's safe to assume that any Muggle having legitimate business is escorted at these times.

Comment: I would think that an anti-Muggle "turning the wrong way" spell wouldn't be effective if your magic spouse tells you about the spell ahead of time and asks you to trust them to lead you the right way. Also, I find it hard to believe that there wouldn't be *some* Muggle willing to give up Muggle conveniences to live in a town with open use of magic. And I think your last paragraph undermines your point: if Muggles can pass through, what would prevent them from staying?

Comment: The anti-Muggle spell making you want to turn around, combined with your spouse telling you that it's just a spell, would most likely result in an argument with the spouse.  That's how marriages tend to work.  In situations like this, Muggle spouses could be issued a device of some sort that negates the anti-Muggle enchantments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest an alternative, based on the fact that Hogsmeade is basically the village that serves Hogwarts, JK Rowling's view of the majority of wizarding society is generally pretty positive and that I believe Dumbledore would have a problem with banning Muggles.

As others have said, on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/hogsmeade), Hogsmeade is described as,

> "The only entirely non-Muggle settlement in Britain."

If we focus on 'entirely non-Muggle' in a different sense, I would argue that this means there are no entirely Muggle households. Here and nowhere else in Britain, witches and wizards can live in peace without secrecy fears while in the village, have lovely local amenities for magic folk, and no 'Mind that house, the Jones's are all Muggles!'

If the village was heavily Malfoy-influenced or featured negatively portrayed Ministry types, I would think differently, but we are always shown a charming, pleasant, vibrant old village. It just doesn't fit to have some weird person appearing to ban newly weds of a certain kind or have spells that would repel Hermione's parents if they came up to visit.

Again, I suggest 'entirely non-Muggle' simply means there are no Muggle households, there is no postman or police presence, no Internet or mobile reception, but that if a family of three witches and their fully-aware Muggle daddy chose to move in, it would be OK.

Comment: But then why would JKR use the word "entirely" as a modifier? Not just muggle free, but entirely so (e.g. no muggle presence whatsoever).

Comment: I just can't believe they are forced out *if* they are married to a witch or wizard and have children, etc. If the Grangers can be invited into Diagon Alley, surely they can visit Hogsmeade. Similarly, if a new teacher at Hogwarts had a Muggle wife but three bouncing magical children, I can't imagine Hogsmeade being off-limits. I think it's Muggle-free in one way, but not every way. She's being Obi-Wan and saying it 'from a certain point of view.'

Comment: So you are saying that the answer to the question is yes: muggles married to witches and wizards can live in Hogsmeade? If the claim is that Hogsmeade is an entirely non-muggle settlement (confirmed by Ron and Hermione in PoA), but defined as no households solely run by muggles, I guess that would also mean Hermione's parents couldn't live there because they are both muggle?

Comment: @Thunderforge - Yes, I think I agree!

Comment: @ThruGog I guess that would then raise the question of *why* muggle parents with a magical child wouldn't be allowed to live there. As noted in the comments of another answer, parents wanting to live near their child's school isn't unheard of even in our muggle world.

Comment: @Thunderforge - See, I just don't think that would be forbidden.